# Add Data to End or Beginning of Excel Cell Macro

Tags: vba, excel, insert

I have searched and learned, and in the end i just did it myself.

Here it is so people dont have to look for it.

This code keeps the Data that is there.

This takes input data in cell P27 of Specified Sheet "Original Data" and places it at the beginning of each cell that has Data in another worksheet "TemplateSheet".

```
Sub copyfileaddresstotemplate()

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Original Data").Activate

            Text = Sheets("Original Data").Range("P27")
            Sheets("TemplateSheet").Activate

            Dim i As Range
            Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select

            For Each i In Selection
            i.Value = Text & i.Value
            Next i
End Sub
```

The Following places text After the cell data

```
Sub copyfileaddresstotemplate()

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Original Data").Activate

            Text = Sheets("Original Data").Range("P27")
            Sheets("TemplateSheet").Activate

            Dim i As Range
            Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select

            For Each i In Selection
            i.Value = i.Value & Text
            Next i
End Sub
```

Happy Coding!

Edit** sorry cant make up my mind, the sub works without public really well if it is in its own module. I can seem to make it work as a public sub for some reason.

Edit** hey it looks different! yes its because the old code posted would delete existing data, if your seeing this for the first time dont worry this works.

Comment: Please don't use [macros] for MS Office or VBA. [macros tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info)

Comment: Sorry, still new. wont happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub copyfileaddresstotemplate()

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Original Data").Activate

            Text = Sheets("Original Data").Range("P27")
            Sheets("TemplateSheet").Activate

            Dim i As Range
            Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select

            For Each i In Selection
            'i.Value = i.Value & Text
            i.Value = Text & i.Value
            Next i
End Sub
```